# Put function outputs to a list in Python

Tags: python, list, printing, output

The aim of the following program is to convert words in 4 characters from `"This"` to `"T***"`, I have done the hard part getting that list and len working.

The problem is the program outputs the answer line by line, I wonder if there is anyway that I can store output back to a list and print it out as a whole sentence?

Thanks.

```
#Define function to translate imported list information
def translate(i):
    if len(i) == 4: #Execute if the length of the text is 4
        translate = i[0] + "***" #Return ***
        return (translate)
    else:
        return (i) #Return original value

#User input sentense for translation
orgSent = input("Pleae enter a sentence:")
orgSent = orgSent.split (" ")

#Print lines
for i in orgSent:
    print(translate(i))
```

Comment: There are fundamentally two completely different ways to think about the problem: either we want to collect the results (first linked duplicate) and join them together into a single item (second linked duplicate); or we want to do our printing on the same line (third linked duplicate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On py 2.x you can add a `,` after `print`:

```
for i in orgSent:
    print translate(i),
```

If you're on py 3.x, then try:

```
for i in orgSent:
    print(translate(i),end=" ")
```

default value of `end` is a newline(`\n`), that's why each word gets printed on a new line.

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension and the `join` method:

```
translated = [translate(i) for i in orgSent]
print(' '.join(translated))
```

List comprehensions basically store the return values of functions in a list, exactly what you want. You could do something like this, for instance:

```
print([i**2 for i in range(5)])
# [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

The `map` function could also be useful - it 'maps' a function to each element of an iterable. In Python 2, it returns a list. However in Python 3 (which I assume you're using) it returns a `map` object, which is also an iterable that you can pass into the `join` function.

```
translated = map(translate, orgSent)
```

The `join` method joins each element of the iterable inside the parentheses with the string before the `.`. For example:

```
lis = ['Hello', 'World!']
print(' '.join(lis))
# Hello World!
```

It's not limited to spaces, you could do something crazy like this:

```
print('foo'.join(lis))
# HellofooWorld!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sgeorge-mn:tmp sgeorge$ python s
Pleae enter a sentence:"my name is suku john george"
my n*** is s*** j*** george
```

You just need to print with `,`. See last line of below pasted code part.

```
#Print lines
for i in orgSent:
    print (translate(i)),
```

For your more understanding:

```
sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ cat tmp.py 
import sys
print "print without ending comma"
print "print without ending comma | ",
sys.stdout.write("print using sys.stdout.write ")

sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ python tmp.py 
print without ending comma
print without ending comma | print using sys.stdout.write sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$
```